# Variables refer to the same instance

Tags: vb.net, list, ienumerable

Within my learning curve I play around with converting `List` and `IEnumerable` between each other.

What I am surprised with is that after executing `EditMyList` procedure `MyIEnumerable` contains the same data for each `DBTable` object as `MyList`. However I have modified `MyList` only, without assigning it to `MyIEnumerable` once `List` has been modified.

Can you explain what happened here and why `MyList` and `MyEInumerable` refer to the same instance?

```
Public Class DBTable
    Public Property TableName As String
    Public Property NumberOfRows As Integer
End Class

Public Sub EditMyList
    Dim MyList As New List(Of DBTable)
    MyList.Add(New DBTable With {.TableName = "A", .NumberOfRows = 1})
    MyList.Add(New DBTable With {.TableName = "B", .NumberOfRows = 2})
    MyList.Add(New DBTable With {.TableName = "C", .NumberOfRows = 3})

    Dim MyIEnumerable As IEnumerable(Of DBTable) = MyList

    For Each item In MyList
        item.NumberOfRows += 10
    Next
End Sub
```

UPDATE: `string` case where at the end b is not equal to a. `String` is also reference type, so assigning one variable to other one we shall copy just reference. However at the end there is different result than in the first example (explained by @Sefe)

```
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
a = "aaa"
b = "bbb"
a = b
' At this point a and b have the same value of "bbb"
a = "xxx"
' At this point I would expect a and b equal to "xxx", however a="xxx" but b="bbb"
```

Comment: What happened here? MyList and MyIEnumerable both refer to the same instance, thus there is only one list, but two references to it. Why it happened? Because you assigned the reference: `Dim MyIEnumerable As IEnumerable(Of DBTable) = MyList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `List` is a reference type. That means it is created on the heap and your `MyList` variable contains just a reference (sometimes incorrectly called "pointer") to the list. When you assign `MyList` to `MyEnumerable` you don't copy the whole list, you just copy the reference. That means all changes you make to the (the one) list, is reflected by all the references.

If you want a new list you need to create it. You can use [the list constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.140).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1):

```
Dim MyIEnumerable As IEnumerable(Of DBTable) = New List(Of DBTable)(MyList)
```

Since you don't need a list, but an `IEnumerable` you can also call the list's `ToArray` method:

```
Dim MyIEnumerable As IEnumerable(Of DBTable) = MyList.ToArray
```

You can also use LINQ:

```
Dim MyIEnumerable As IEnumerable(Of DBTable) = MyList.ToList
```

As far as the behavior of `String` is concerned, strings in .net are *immutable*. That means once created, they can not be changed. String operations (for example concatinations) will always create new strings. In other words: the copy operation you have to do manually for your lists is done automatically for strings. That's why you see similar behavior for strings as for value types.

Also, the assignment operation in your question would also still behave the same if strings were mutable. When you assign `a = "xxx"`, you update the reference of `a`from `"bbb"` to `"xxx"`. That however does not affect b, which still keeps its old reference.

Comment: Then how shall I assign `MyList` to 'MyEnumerable' to get a separate instance?

Comment: You need to create a new list and copy the elements from one list to the other. Check my edit.

Comment: Things become clearer. However why in case of two `string` variables (also reference type) it behaves differently? See my update.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ToList()` extension method for creating another `List`

```
Dim newCollection = MyList.ToList()
```

But notice that instances of `DBTable` still will reference to the same items

For creating "full" copy you need create new instances of `DBTable` for every item in the collection

```
Dim newCollection = MyList.Select(Function(item)
                                      return new DBTable
                                      {
                                          .TableName = item.TableName,
                                          .NumberOfRows = item.NumberOfRows
                                      }
                                  End Function).ToList()


For Each item in MyList
    item.NumberOfrows += 10 ' will not affect on the newCollection items
Next
```

Comment: That won't solve the problem, because `Select` works on the existing list. Change an item in the list and the select will reflect it.

Comment: `Select` do exactly what OP asks it create new IEnumerable which can be enumerated

Comment: No, he wants an enumerable that doesnt change with the original. The old list can be already enumerated.

Comment: Thanks - updated my answer, but his main problem not a List - his problem he want that elements of the collection will not change